# Updating many records with order clause

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I table words with fields: rating and occurrence.

```
TABLE: words
+----+----------+----------------+
| id |occurrence| rating         |
+----+----------+----------------+
| 1  | 0.2      |       2        |
| 2  | 0.1      |       1        |
| 3  | 0.5      |       3        |
+----+----------+----------------+
```

Rating It's a index of ordered by occurrence (asc) column.
So firstly I have to sort all records, and then for every record set index in rating column. How to do it in SQL ?

Comment: Can you please rephrase this plesae ? *Rating it's a index of ordered by*? What is the final outcome you are looking at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE   words, (SELECT @rating := 0) init
SET      rating = (@rating := @rating + 1)
ORDER BY occurrence
```